# Inductance of parallel wires with parallel and antiparallel running currents

Tags: inductance

The well-documented mutual inductance of a pair of parallel wires with antiparallel running current is $$L=\frac{\mu_0 l}{\pi}\left(\ln{\frac{d}{a}+\frac{1}{4}}\right).$$

This can be thought of as the return current next to the outgoing current from a battery say.  My question is, what if the current was going in the same direction, with the current running parallel to eachother as well as the wires running parallel to eachother.  What would the inductance be then?  And would it take on the same value as the antiparallel current running case?  Another way to say this, is inductance purely geometry dependant, or does it depend on the current running in the wires and what magnitude the current is also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the magnetic flux linked with a current in a long straight wire of radius *a*? The flux per unit length outside the wire is
$$\int_a^\inf \frac{\mu_0I dr}{2 \pi r}=\frac{\mu_0I}{2 \pi}\ \left[\ln r \right]_a^\inf.$$ 
Clearly this doesn't converge. The reason is that we don't have a return route for the current; we don't have a circuit.

The same thing will happen for two parallel wires carrying current in the same direction. A long way from the wires compared with their separation, the field will be the same as for a single wire carrying the sum of the individual currents, so the same non-convergence will occur. The self-inductance for this set-up by itself isn't defined.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Philip

Comment: I saw a demonstration of a sparkplug wire for an engine. It had two plug wires in parallel but not connected and the engine was running, as the wires were separated from one end, it eventually started to misfire as the amount of wire in parallel was reduced...